# multiple jQuery ajax calls - previous calls are throwing fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a login form on my website that uses ajax to send the login information to php. 
Once logged in, the user can then logout and be redirected to the login page again. My problem is that every time you login after logging out previously, the `fail` method triggers with an `abort` error message.

For example:

```
*user logs in successfully*
*user logs out*
*user logs in successfully*
The following error occurred: abort abort
*user logs out*
*user logs in successfully*
The following error occurred: abort abort
The following error occurred: abort abort
*user logs out*
```

It just keeps on going on like that, with more errors being thrown each time.

When the user clicks on the login form submit button, this is the code that is executed:

```
p.onMouseClick = function()
{
    var savedRef = this;

    $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e){

        if(this.request){
            this.request.abort();
        }

        var form = $(this);
        var inputs = form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var serializedData = form.serialize();

        inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        this.request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://***********/login.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        this.request.done($.proxy(function(result){
            if(result['returnCode'] == 1){
                playerInfo = new PlayerInfo(result['returnMessage']);
                savedRef.loggedIn();
                inputs.prop("disabled", true);
            }
        }, this));
        this.request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                    "The following error occured: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });
        this.request.always(function(){
            inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

Comment: Is the `serializedData` value same on all attempts of ajax call ? i mean in successfull login and when it throws errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that the error is because this:

```
if(this.request){
    this.request.abort();
}
```

I think it's for prevent the function of doing a call during another call.
Try to do this instead:

```
if(this.request){
    return false;
}
```

Also, and very important. take the form.submit event out of the click event.

on click event just call submit function:

```
var savedRef;

p.onMouseClick = function()
{   
    savedRef = this;    
    $('#loginForm').submit();
};

$('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e){

    if(this.request){
        this.request.abort();
    }        

    var form = $(this);
    var inputs = form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = form.serialize();

    inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    this.request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://***********/login.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    this.request.done($.proxy(function(result){
        if(result['returnCode'] == 1){
            playerInfo = new PlayerInfo(result['returnMessage']);
            savedRef.loggedIn();
            inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }, this));
    this.request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
    this.request.always(function(){
        inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem. As you correctly pointed out, the ($form).on('submit'..) was inside the click. Therefore every time the form was clicked a new listener was added.